# Mentioning a professor's work in the statement of purpose when they aren't the first author

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, computer-science, statement-of-purpose

I am applying to graduate school (USA, computer science/machine learning), and one potential PhD advisor is Bob. Many of the papers that he coauthored overlap significantly with my interests. One of these papers is

> Moving basket weaving out of water and onto land improves efficiency
>
> Authors: Alice, Bob, Charlie

Bob is Alice's advisor, and Charlie has since become faculty at a different university.

Would it be OK to include a line like:

> Professor Bob's research on the effect of the basket weaving environment is interesting because blah blah

despite Bob being second author?

This is Bob's only basket-weaving-environment paper, but he has many papers (in several different author positions) for related fields- these already received mentions in the SOP. I have not talked to Bob.

But the specifics don't matter too much, I am mainly concerned with writing "Professor Bob's research on blank" where "blank's" primary author was not Bob.

Comment: I'm going to remove my other comments because this has gotten quite chatty, but I hope you can update your question with some of the additional details you've mentioned (comments are ephemeral and are not meant to last). Key points: you haven't had any correspondence, Bob's last-author papers re: your interests, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116596/discussion-between-daniel-m-and-bryan-krause).

Edit: That button did not do what I intended, but at least it has a log of the comments.